# Code Composer Studio MSPFR6989 variables&expressions won’t come up

Tags: microcontroller, ccscene

I am using CCS to program a MSPFR6989 and I’ve debugged and the code is working but I can’t get variables or registers to come up. It remains blank. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTj29.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use double click onto your variables and choose watch expression. You can find your variables under expression from now. If it shows you its name but a red error message try step by step debugging, works for me everytime.